# Help understandaing this mySQL query with ORDER BY and CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to understand this mySQL query. It supposedly searches the table 'items' with search keyword 'brown fox lazy dog' and returns the result based on its relevancy or number of times it occurs in the records.

```
SELECT *
FROM `items`
WHERE `description` LIKE 'quick'
AND (
  `description` LIKE 'brown'
  OR `description` LIKE 'fox'
  OR `description` LIKE 'lazy'
  OR `description` LIKE 'dog'
)
ORDER BY (
  (
    CASE WHEN `description` LIKE 'brown'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) + (
    CASE WHEN `description` LIKE 'fox'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) + (
    CASE WHEN `description` LIKE 'lazy'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) + (
    CASE WHEN `description` LIKE 'dog'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  )
) DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

The part which I dont understand is in the part in the ORDER BY and  CASE clauses. Say a particular record matches all 4 keywords being searched, we get ORDER BY (4)? How is this 4 linked to the parrticular row being considered? What I understand is that ORDER BY is normally used on a column and not a number? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are missing wildcards and that at the moment it can return no results. (should be `LIKE '%dog%'` etc)

Answer (score 2):

ORDER BY can be used on any value derived from the fields in each row. In this case, we're ordering on the number of the important words appearing in the `description` field. So as you say, if a particular record matches all 4 keywords, then it gets a 4, and ends up at the top of the (descending) ordering. If the record matches only one of the keywords, it gets a 1 and ends up toward the bottom. You can even say ORDER BY RAND(), which does exactly what you'd expect. ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 is a very common idiom to choose a single row at random from a table. However, do **not** use ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 on big tables, because it still generates a random number for each row (very expensive) just to figure out which one is the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

the number here refers to the column to use for ordering results, the first column would be 1.
couldn't find a reference for that online, but I discovered that accidentally and it comes in handy sometimes.

Comment: No, that's not applicable in this case.  `ORDER BY <literal number>` gives the behavior you describe -- that is, sorting on a column identified by ordinal position -- but this is `ORDER BY <computed value expression>`.

Comment: interesting, anyway couldn't find either of them on mysql's online ref.

Answer (score 0):

This query is used to order by items let's say by 'relevance' ...

The order by part will be for example if a description is like '%dog%' order by will take 1 and if the same description contain 'lazy' order by will be 1 + 1; that mean that current row had the two keywords 'dog' and 'lazy'. and so on.

This query is ordering items by "The description who contains the max of keyword", so if a row record matches all 4 keywords, then it gets a 4, and ends up at the top of the (descending) ordering. If the row record matches only one of the keywords, it gets a 1 and ends up toward the bottom.